# Ole Automation and IIS

Tags: iis, installation, inno-setup

I am investigating moving our installer over to use InnoSetup and would like to know if there is a good reference for configuring IIS through Ole Objects and is it possible to do so or would it be simpler (better?) to do this by calling a batch file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the above.

- If you are using IIS7 or later, you can use the command-line tools like `%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe` that you can use to do administration and setup.
- using IIS6 you can use WMI, exposed at `winmgmts://localhost/root/MicrosoftIISv2`

But, Why would you not use WiX ?   There is IIS intelligence built-in to Wix.

Comment: I would hit up ADSI for IIS6 configuration rather than using WMI. The WMI interfaces aren't as flexible as the intention of WMI is for management more than configuration. WMI just wraps parts of ADSI and parts of ABO in a somewhat unsatisfactory way.

Comment: Because the more I use windows MSI based installers the more I hate them.  (Just copy over the changed files i tell you to dam it!)

Comment: And the batch file would be just a list of commands for appcmd.exe

Comment: Maybe you used the wrong setup authoring tool. Windows Installer offers better Windows integration than a custom installation engine.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't choose InstallShield just inherited it